# Laravel Login post method redirects to gives blank page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

---

The output should display the token on /login . But as soon I click the login button, I am directed to a blank page.

---

*There are similar questions asked but I still wasn't able to solve. Please if anyone could help me with it.*

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    
    function login(Request $req)
    {
        return $req->input;
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::post("/login",[UserController::class,'login']);
```

The name, email and password records are visible in the database.

Model - User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Login page

```
            <form action="login" method="POST">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    @csrf
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: You should use return $req->input('email'); or return $req->all();

Comment: @Aqib Javed thanks a lot! It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `action` attribute in form tag.

It seems to be correct to use `/login` instead of `login`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: `$req->input` returns `input` field value of request, not all request fields. Use `$req->all()`, instead of `$req->input`.